# Is it safe to replace CoTaskMemAlloc with malloc on Mac

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, mono

I'm trying to port Unity Windows c++ dll to OSX.
The code uses CoTaskMemAlloc when passing data to managed C# side as out parameter:

```
*faces = (RECT**)::CoTaskMemAlloc(fsize); // c++
```

The managed side frees memory with

```
Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(faces); // c#
```

Compilation fails on Mac:

```
 error: no member named 'CoTaskMemAlloc' in the global namespace
```

Is it safe to replace CoTaskMemAlloc with malloc in non-windows platforms?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/palrt/comem.cpp#L14

Comment: Don't use `malloc(3)` in c++.... that's completely discouraged.  Don'tt know in c#, but I suppose it happens the same.

Comment: Similar question on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/10748) and new version of [HansPassant's link](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/coreclr/palrt/comem.cpp)